Site Collection is "Running out of space" message while 99% of space is still available
Over the last several weeks I started getting the messages from SharePoint Onlineno-reply@sharepointonline.com claiming that my SharePoint sites are running out of space:


However, the opposite is true: we almost used none of it. There is plenty of space left.

The storage space alerts notifications are not configured:

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

none of my tenants show this.

is retention active for the SharePoint site?

No, there are no retentions

It's a glitch at the Microsoft's back end. One way to get around this is to change the site quota to anything and set it back to the original value. In my case, I reduced the quota by 1 GB and the yellow ribbon went away.

:D :D :D :D :D :D
